# How to delete all the duplicates row based on two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame where I want to delete duplicates rows, but I want to delete them only if a value from another column is the same for all the rows. (To be more clear I want to delete the duplicates rows which have the same "Number" value for all rows)

There is a example of my data frame :

```
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
                 "Number" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And the result I expect is :

```
result <- data.frame("Name" = c("b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
                     "Number" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Always better to copy and paste what the current and expected output look like. Eliminates the need to first run your code.

Comment: You can use two different functions `library(dplyr)` `duplicated():` for identifying duplicated elements and `unique()`: for extracting unique elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `group_by` `Name` and remove groups which have more than 1 row and have only one distinct value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(!(n_distinct(Number) == 1 & n() > 1))

#  Name  Number
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 b          2
#2 b          2
#3 b          3
```

and using base R `ave`, the same logic can be written as

```
df[with(df, !as.logical(ave(Number, Name, FUN = function(x) 
            length(unique(x)) == 1 & length(x) > 1))), ]
```

Comment: Why `n()` is required? Won't `filter(n_distinct(Number) > 1)` be sufficient?

Comment: because if a particular group has only one row then it wouldn't be a duplicate and `n_distinct(Number) == 1` would still satisfy. Hoping that I have understood OP correctly, too few rows to make a call actually.

Comment: @yarnabrina wait. I think I didn't read your comment correctly initially. `filter(n_distinct(Number) > 1)` should work too I guess.

Comment: Based on your reply I did some test around to understand the behaviour of ave() and I managed to find a solution which is close to yours.
df <- df[!as.logical(ave(df$Number, df$Name, FUN = function (x) length(unique(x)) == 1)),]

Comment: @RonakShah No, in case a group has only one row, `filter(n_distinct(Number) > 1)` also will filter that out. So, `n()` is required.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")
df <- data.table("Name" = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                 "Number" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3))

df[, if (uniqueN(Number)!=1 || .N==1) .SD, Name]
```

and here is a solution with base `R`:

```
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                 "Number" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[as.logical(ave(df$Number, df$Name, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))!=1 || length(x)==1)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(Number) > 1] , Name]
#   Name Number
#1:    b      1
#2:    b      2
#3:    b      3
#4:    c      4
#5:    c      5
#6:    c      5
```